# Ruby on Rails query where equal to two concatenated columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My customer model has a `first_name` and `last_name` field. I can query the model with the following code:

```
Customer.where(first_name: "John").where(last_name "Doe")
```

However, I want to query the model like this:

```
Customer.where(full_name: "John Doe")
```

But I do not have a full_name column. How can I accomplish this without creating a `full_name` field?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the CONCAT operator in SQL:

```
Customer.where("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) = ?", full_name)
```

Which actually might make sense if you are creating something like a search function with like/ilike:

```
Customer.where("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{full_name}%")
```

Comment: This is going to require the full_name being searched for to be perfect which may not be an issue depending on what the data in the Customer table looks like/where full_name is coming from.  For (in)accuracy reasons you may want to replace whitespace in the full_name with a %.

Answer (score 1):

You can not, if you do not have a full name attribute you can not query by a full name and any try to do it using ActiveRecord in a single query will add an extra complexity to your app (or model), but to solve your question with simplicity you can add a scope to your Customer model, or a class method passing the first and last name as argument.

Using a **scope**

```
scope :by_full_name, (lambda { |first_name, last_name|
  where(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
})
```

using a static **(class) method**:

```
def self.by_full_name(first_name, last_name)
  where(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
end
```

Personally, due to simplicity and clearly code I prefer to use scopes instead of class methods if no extra logic is required.

Comment: Its actually pretty trivial to do with a single line of sql. Also class methods in ruby are not static and have nothing to with static methods in languages like PHP.

Comment: Hi max!, I know, but I prefer simplicity over join to strings in a variable to pass it to another (native, almost raw) sql query using CONCAT. Your solution is perfectly valid, but I prefer other more simple ways, I think is about preferences....

Comment: But this does not even answer the question. If the requirement is that you should be able to search for users in a single field  this just fails.

Comment: It does, but in a different way than yours. In relation to static methods, I call class methods as "static" not thinking about PHP, but about Java, it is an over simplification to resume.

Comment: How does you answer take a single string from say a text input and use it to query? You're presenting a method with an arity of 2.

Comment: Max, You do not have to convince me, I have my idea and I do not reject yours, with my response I show what I would do, nothing more, and I prefer to do so, it is another point of view and it is easy to respect, It is the richness of diversity.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Max, split the name and query on both fields as in your question.

```
scope :where_full_name, ->(full_name) do 
  (first_name, last_name) = full_name.split(/\s+/)
  where first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name
end
```

Then use

```
Customer.where_full_name 'Betty Davis'
```

This won't work for names like `Joan van der Graff`.

Comment: This only  covers the simplest possible case. I don't really get why people are so allergic to SQL strings that they prefer something long and convoluted and not even functional. `CONCAT` is part of the SQL standard so that you can't even say that portability is an issue.

Comment: You could do something like `first_name, *middle_names, last_name = full_name.split(/\s+/)`

Comment: @max well technically MSSQL only started supporting concat version > 2012 so there **could** be some portability issues

Comment: @engineersmnky true, but I don't think anything will be particularly smooth when using MSSQL and AR together.

Comment: @max doing a concat on the table columns will prevent the database from taking advantage of any existing indexes and will need a new index to be created (which will be less database agnostic than concat) and likely require a stored calculated field thus duplicating the contents of the columns and increasing insertion time.  An index may not be necessary for a small dataset though and of course if you start the like with a % will provide no benefit so it may not apply to this situation but future performance might have something to do with it?

Comment: @user3334690 `first_name, *middle_names, last_name` fails for the same reason as you can't actually expect to be able to programatically split between fore and surnames. Consider  "Jean Michael van der Waal" for example.

Comment: @user3334690 there are of course performance implications but thats somewhat beyond the scope of this question.